# Create df column as json of row

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the below code, that iterates through the df and creates an additional column `new` with a dict of the other columns. Is there a better way to achieve this without using iterrows? My actual dataset is much larger and iterating through rows is not performant.

Code

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Nick', 'Jim', 'John'],
        'Age':[20, 21, 35, 11]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i, 'new'] = json.dumps(row.to_dict())

print(df)
```

Output

```
  Name  Age                          new
0   Tom   20   {"Name": "Tom", "Age": 20}
1  Nick   21  {"Name": "Nick", "Age": 21}
2   Jim   35   {"Name": "Jim", "Age": 35}
3  John   11  {"Name": "John", "Age": 11}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `df.to_dict` with `df.join`

```
out = df.join(pd.Series(df.to_dict('records'),index=df.index,name='new'))
```

---

```
print(out)

   Name  Age                          new
0   Tom   20   {'Name': 'Tom', 'Age': 20}
1  Nick   21  {'Name': 'Nick', 'Age': 21}
2   Jim   35   {'Name': 'Jim', 'Age': 35}
3  John   11  {'Name': 'John', 'Age': 11}
```